# During HMVC installation an error occurred, how to remove?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I am new to codeigniter HMVC structure, following this link for installation.
https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src

Have performed all steps but when reached on step 12 it shows error.

**Steps:**

1. Start with a clean CI install
2. Set $config[‘base_url’] correctly for your installation
3. Access the URL /index.php/welcome => shows Welcome to CodeIgniter
4. Drop Modular Extensions third_party files into the application/third_party directory
5. Drop Modular Extensions core files into application/core, the MY_Controller.php file is not required unless you wish to create
   your own controller extension
6. Access the URL /index.php/welcome => shows Welcome to CodeIgniter
7. Create module directory structure application/modules/welcome/controllers
8. Move controller application/controllers/welcome.php to application/modules/welcome/controllers/welcome.php
9. Access the URL /index.php/welcome => shows Welcome to CodeIgniter
10. Create directory application/modules/welcome/views
11. Move view application/views/welcome_message.php to application/modules/welcome/views/welcome_message.php
12. Access the URL /index.php/welcome => shows Welcome to CodeIgniter

**Error:**

Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

How to solve it please? is any change need in route/config.index etc? should i copy-paste config folder to each module as well? currently they all are default.
My CI version is latest 3.0.3
and in config index_page is empty instead of index.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

also checked by adding index.php instead of empty.
one more thing i searched online and also tried by capitalizing View,Controler etc folder names but nothing happened.

Comment: Still not fixed? I've same problem too.

Comment: not fixed yet, tried alot, now moved back to codeigniter simple, will try it later

Comment: I started from clean CI again. It worked. But only problem now is its printing its view twice.

Comment: do you have your view folder in main application folder aswell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this HMVC version :

https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/src/b889da049fd78bd5beff8d7ef70916b60c3d6665?at=codeigniter-3.x